# Cloning a hashmap using a reference to another hashmap

Tags: rust, reference, hashmap

I have a reference to a hashmap (`data` in the code below) which I want to clone into a new, owned hashmap. Cloning the reference gives me a new reference, which is not what I need.

I also tried doing an iter + map over the `data` reference and cloning the key and value pairs individually followed by a collect, but that also does not work. Here is a minimal working example:

```rust
use core::cell::Cell;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Dummy<K, V> {
    dirty: Rc<Cell<bool>>,
    data: Cell<Option<HashMap<K, HashSet<V>>>>,
}

impl<K, V> Dummy<K, V> {
    fn persist(&self, prefix: &str, data: &HashMap<K, HashSet<V>>) {
        self.dirty.set(true);
        self.data.set(Some(data.clone()));
    }
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:14:28
   |
14 |         self.data.set(Some(data.clone()));
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::collections::HashMap`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `std::collections::HashMap<K, std::collections::HashSet<V>>`
              found type `&std::collections::HashMap<K, std::collections::HashSet<V>>`
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=01f983a97475341f0525803dc687fc4b))

The purpose of this code is to observe the contents of the hashmap on through the `Dummy` struct, which is used for unit testing.

I guess this problem is because given the generic types there is no way to determine how to deeply clone the key and value objects?

Is there a way to create a new hashmap given a reference to an existing hashmap?

Comment: What if you use `impl<K: Clone, V: Clone>` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the comment suggested this is a slightly unfortunate interaction of how Rust looks up methods via references / autoderef:

[The implementation of `Clone` on `HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-Clone) requires the keys and the values (and the hasher) to be `Clone` as well. This makes sense since we can only clone the `HashMap` if we can clone its content. If any of those do not implement `Clone`, the `HashMap` does not implement `Clone`.

Your `impl<K, V>` has no bounds regarding `Clone`. So why does the call to `data.clone()` even work at all? That's because there is an [implementation of `Clone` on any reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html#impl-Clone), which gives you a copy of the reference.

Since your `impl<K, V>` has no bounds on `K` or `V`, the compiler will only find the `Clone`-implementation on the primitive `&`-type to be applicable. If you require `K: Clone, V: Clone`, the `HashMap`'s own `Clone`-impl applies (`S` is already `Clone` by default).

See this example:

```
// This returns a cloned HashMap
// because Rust uses the Clone-implementation on HashMap
fn do_clone<K: Clone, V: Clone>(data: &HashMap<K,V>) -> HashMap<K, V> {
    data.clone()
}

// There is no viable Clone-implementation on the HashMap
// because K & V are not Clone. But there is an implementation
// on the primitive reference type.
fn do_clone_ref<K, V>(data: &HashMap<K,V>) -> &HashMap<K, V> {
    data.clone()
}
```